# Type 'string | string[]' is not assignable to type 'string' - typescript type error

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to use the [Accordion](https://ng-lightning.github.io/ng-lightning/#/components/accordion) component from the [Ng-Lightning](https://ng-lightning.github.io/ng-lightning/#/) library.

My html:

```
<ul ngl-accordion [(activeName)]="active">
  <ng-template nglAccordionSection name="B" label="Accordion Title A">This is the content area for section A
  </ng-template>
</ul>

<div class="slds-m-top_large">Active Section Name: <b>{{ active | json }}</b></div>
```

and my component file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-list-item',
  templateUrl: './list-item.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./list-item.component.scss']
})
export class SuggestedReferenceListItemComponent implements OnInit {

  active='B';

  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit(): void {}

}
```

I'm seeing the following warning when trying to compile my code:

```
Error: src/app/list-item/list-item.component.html:3:35 - error TS2322: Type 'string | string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.
Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.

<ul ngl-accordion [(activeName)]="active">
```

Could anyone tell me why I'm seeing that warning and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Ng-Lightning, activeName is defined here :

[image]

And your component **active='B';** is defined only like a string.

So, u can try :

```
active: string | string[] = 'B';
```

or if it really doesn't work

```
active: any = 'B';
```